# iOS - Best practice for handling network response cross ViewControllers

Tags: ios, multithreading, networking

For example,
There are 3 sequencial view controllers, A, B, C, in the navigation stack.
After sending an async network request in view controller C in the background thread,
User may go back to B or A.

What is the best way to handle the network response no matter where the current view controller is?

Thanks.

Comment: The best way is to not have the ViewControllers send the requests in the first place, but have another 'Controller' object deal with the network comms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the three view controllers may be interested in the response, don't make it in any of them. Create a class, let's say `NetworkHandler` with method `- (void) makeRequest`. You can make it a singleton or add it to the `AppDelegate`.

In C, call this method.

When `- (void) makeRequest` finishes the call, make an `NSNotification` and make all three view controllers register to this notification.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to have a Singleton class. You can have some delegate also to notify the controller that response received and do the respective action.